# FCGI scripts failing to run on VPS using CentOS 5.5 & Apache, prevents Trac running

Tags: permissions, centos5, trac, 500-error, fcgi

Attempting to install Trac on my VPS has been a nightmare. I'm fairly certain that I've got all the necessary files and the system will run if I use the standalone server. However trying to get it set up to be accessible through Apache is proving difficult.

In order to test this I've created a very simple FGCI script, to check where the problem lies. The script is at the url http://trac.1webservices.co.uk/test.fcgi

The directory httpdocs is set to 755, myuser:psaserv
The file test.fcgi is set to 755 myuser:psacln (was previously psaserv)
Both were created from root SSH so originally root:root

The .htaccess file reads as follows:

```
<Files *.cgi>
SetHandler fastcgi-script
</Files>
```

Test.fcgi is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'test'
```

When I run the script I get a 500 error and the following in my suexec_log file

```
[2012-03-08 12:17:31]: target uid/gid (10001/506 or 505) mismatch with directory (10001/505) or program (10001/505)
[2012-03-08 12:37:57]: uid: (10001/myuser) gid: (506/506) cmd: test.fcgi
```

Can anyone suggest anything, or tell me (preferably with a link to some actual instructions rather than the poor docs on Trac's website) an alternative way to get Trac running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's your SuexecUserGroup setting in the httpd.conf file

It sounds like it should be set to the following to match the test.fcgi file ownership:

SuexecUserGroup myuser psacln

Comment: There isn't a line with that in it; should I add it to httpd.conf or one of the .conf files in the conf.d directory?

Comment: Add it to the virtualhost section related to the trac installation. If there isn't a section just for it, add it to the main httpd.conf for now.

Comment: Added that, still get the 500 error. From error_log:
`[Thu Mar 08 16:16:43 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: server /var/www/vhosts/1webservices.co.uk/subdomains/trac/httpdocs/test.fcgi(13467) started
test
[Thu Mar 08 16:16:46 2012] [notice] mod_fcgid: process /var/www/vhosts/1webservices.co.uk/subdomains/trac/httpdocs/test.fcgi(13467) exit(communication error), terminated by calling exit(), return code: 0`
However message in suexec_log has changed
`[2012-03-08 16:16:43]: uid: (10001/myuser) gid: (506/506) cmd: test.fcgi`

Comment: OK, so that change did fix it, I just needed to change test.fcgi to 

`echo "hello" >> /tmp/testfile`
However I get a 404 error from my index.fcgi which contains the code:
`#!/bin/bash`
`export TRAC_ENV="/usr/share/trac/"`
`exec /usr/share/trac/cgi-bin/trac.fcgi`

Comment: Right, had to change the owner of the trac.fcgi file referenced in index.fcgi and it works. All to do with permissions!